# Missing crawled properties for custom user profile properties

Tags: search, crawling, managed-property

I have 2 custom (RegionID and SalesID) in user profile. Both are populated with values. I reset the content index, made sure values are populated for these fields, did multiple full crawl. I made sure from CA that "metadata properties > category" people and sharepoint's bulk crawled property settings are checked for automatically generate a new managed property...

I see SalesID but no Managed property. For example, owsSalesID is not there for me to map it.
RegionID does not even show up as a crawl property nor Managed property.

I went through the every single step (from here http://sharepointgeorge.com/2010/configuring-enterprise-search-sharepoint-2010) to make sure everything is properly configured.

What are my options now? Is there a powershell way to force add the crawl properties along with the Managed Property? If yes, how?

Any help will be appreciated. I am on this since Monday and it's not going anywhere.

Comment: I think your crawled properties would be called People:SalesID and People:RegionID not owsSalesID or owsRegionID

Comment: @MLF: People:SalesID or People:RegionID does not exists either.

Comment: http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2010/05/26/creating-enterprise-search-metadata-property-mappings-with-powershell.aspx Let me try Corey Roth's method and see if it works.

Comment: When you edit the SalesID and RegionID profile properties, under the Search Settings section is the Indexed checkbox checked?

Comment: @MLF: Oh yes, that box has been checked as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer on behalf of Donna (CW)
Just added them manually using PS: Here is the code

Adding both Crawl and Managed Property

```
$searchapp = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication "Search Service Application" 
$category = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataCategory –Identity People -SearchApplication $searchapp
$crawledproperty = New-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataCrawledProperty -SearchApplication $searchapp -Category $category -VariantType 31 -PropSet "00110329-0000-0110-c000-000000111146" -Name People:SalesID -IsNameEnum $false 
$managedproperty = New-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataManagedProperty -SearchApplication $searchapp -Name SalesID -Type 1
New-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataMapping -SearchApplication $searchapp -ManagedProperty $managedproperty -CrawledProperty $crawledproperty
```